# PDO bind parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm building simple query builder, and I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to secure mysql queries with normal functions to the similar level as it is done using `->execute(array(':param:' => ...` ?
2. Is it possible to use many variables in one query, give them the same names (the ones after the semicolon), and then bind them one by one?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase that so that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If I understand you correctly, you would like to know if it possible to replicate the functionality of `bindParam` with the standard `mysql_*` functions?

   Short answer is **no**. Please do not use the mysql functions at all, use `mysqli` or `PDO` as these provide you with the true security when it comes to `prepared statements`. They can also provide much better query performance as the SQL is able to be pre-optimised for the database.
2. You will have to define each parameter separately (even if it is the same value). You could also pass a simple array to the `execute()` method call, but you do not then have the option to explicitly define the parameter types.

Within your function use some thing like this:

```
$name = "fred";
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE first_name = ? OR last_name = ?");
for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
  $statement->bindParam($x, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$statement->execute();
```